# could not find libicui18n.so.58 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, c++, pip, ubuntu-16.04, pyicu

I am trying to install pyicu in virtualenv

```
 pip install PyICU
```

it installed but while trying to use its method, it through below error

```
from icu import *


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/harish/anaconda3/envs/newcondaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/icu/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from _icu import *
ImportError: libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

then tried installing icu binaries with below command

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

still same issue persist

**My system details**

1. os details:Ubuntu 16.04
2. python version : 3.5
3. installing inside virtualenv using pip

Answer (score 1):

Installing pyicu from the conda-forge channel can be achieved by adding conda-forge to your channels with:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Once the conda-forge channel has been enabled, pyicu can be installed with:

```
conda install pyicu
```

this solves the problem and it will install pyicu with dependencies

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  Did it not work for someone?